# In verilog, how to double the high signal and keep the low signal same

Tags: verilog

[the picture indicates what I want the output signal is: the high signal double and the low signal keep same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHaLK.png)

I wrote the code like:

```
integer x=0, count_valid=1, count_down=0;
reg valid_1, valid_reg;
always@(posedge clk)
begin
  if(tag==1) begin
   if(valid) begin
    count_valid <= count_valid +1;
    x<=x+1;
    valid_reg <= 1;
    end
    else begin
     x<=0;
     count_down <= count_down+1;
     if(count_valid>0) begin
     valid_reg <= 1;
     count_valid <= count_valid -1;
    end
    else if(count_down>0) begin
     valid_reg <= 0;
     count_down <= count_down-1;
     end
   end
  end
  else begin
  valid_reg <= valid;
  if (valid) x<=x+1;
  else x<=0;
  end
  valid_1 <= valid_reg;
end
```

`valid` is the original signal in the picture and `valid_reg` is the modified signal. the `count_valid` is used to count how many cycles for high and use it to sub one to achieve the doubling. then `count_down`  is for counting the cycles of low signal. but I realized when valid high the `valid_reg` will high.

can anyone give me some idea how to make the low signal run same cycles in output signal? any idea is also great.

Comment: Your  picture of the clocks is missing the source clock, which you have the used the clock divisions of. This needs to be in the diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention if the input signal was periodic or not.  Given the fact that your output is stretched over time, if the input is not periodic, then you would need infinite storage to keep track of what the input signal looked like.  If it is periodic, or quasi-periodic, you can do something like below.
Keep track of the high count and low count in one block, and generate the output signal in another block, using the current registered values of the counts.  Getting the output's first edge to line up with the input's is kind of tricky, requiring a mux, selected depending on whether it's the first time through the loop or not.

```
integer count, count_q, countdown, countdown_q, outcount;
logic valid_q, valid_reg, out_q;
logic new;
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n)
  begin
  if(~reset_n)
    begin
    if(~reset_n)
      begin
      new <= 1;
      valid_q <= 0;
      count_q <= 0;
      countdown_q <= 0;
      end
    else
      begin
      valid_q <= valid;
      if(valid & ~valid_q)//rising edge
        begin
        count <= 1;
        countdown_q <= countdown;
        end
      else if(~valid & valid_q)//falling edge
        begin
        new <= 0;
        count_q <= count;
        countdown <= 1;
        end
      else if(valid)
        count <= count+1;
      else 
        countdown <= countdown+1;
      end
    end
  end
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n)
  begin
  if(~reset)
    begin
    outcount <= 0;
    out_q <= 0;
    end
  else
    begin
    if(new & valid & ~valid_q)
      begin
      out_q <= 1;
      outcount <= 2;//valid_reg is already high here
      end
    else
      if(out_q && (outcount == (count_q<<1)))
        begin
        out_q <= 0;
        outcount <= 1;
        end
      else if(~out_q && (outcount == (countdown_q)))
        begin
        out_q <= 1;
        outcount <= 1;
        end
      else
        outcount <= outcount + 1;
    end
  end
assign valid_reg = new? valid : out_q;//this gets your initial rising edge lined up
```